# Redshift error while executing multiple queries

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are executing multiple RedShift queries(CREATE and INSERT) through Python executed by Glue. After executing few queries, we are getting the below error for a CREATE query. If we run the query individually it works fine. I wanted to know if there are any RedShift limitations to run multiple queries together. The error is as below

```
{'S':'ERROR', 'C':'XX000', 'M':  '\n -- is_only_metadata_temp_creator - \n query: 0\n location: StorageOidManager.cpp:524\n process:padbmaster [pid=30819] \n -----------\n','F':'../src/external_catalog/external_catalog_api.cpp','L':'943','R':'localize_external_table'}
```

Comment: Questions.  Is the data in an external table?  Are the queries colliding on a single S3 file?  External tables are, well, external to Redshift and there is no coherency control applied over them.

Comment: No Bill, but we are doing cross database queries. The tables are all using RedShift managed storage

Comment: The error you are getting is specifying an external table. If not S3 then are these queries referencing federated databases (not in the same physical cluster)?  If this isn't the right path then can you provide some more detail on your database setup?

Comment: We have two databases in the cluster. Lets say DB1 and DB2. In DB1 we have a table T1. We are trying to do an insert into T2 in DB2 by selecting data from T1. This is not happening in all scenarios. After we run multiple of these inserts, we get the error for one table

Comment: i have same problem with cross DB views, e.g. a view on one DB points to a table in another DB in same cluster. Sometimes, in a client toll that simply queries the view, Redshift returns this error. How to profile and resolve it?